# Scraping aspx with Python mechanize - getting search results

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I've been trying to scrape Congressional financial disclosure [reports](http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-search.aspx) using mechanize; the form submits successfully, but I can't locate any of the search results. My script is below:

```
br = Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open('http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-search.aspx')
br.select_form(name='aspnetForm')
br.set_all_readonly(False)
br['filing_year'] = ['2008']

response = br.submit(name='search_btn')
html = response.read()
```

I'm new to scraping, and would appreciate any corrections/advice on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you okay with an alternative solution using `selenium`?

Comment: @alecxe Sure, if that's the preferred method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative solution that involves a real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) tool.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# initialize webdriver instance and visit url
url = "http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-search.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

# find select tag and select 2008
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphMain_txbFiling_year'))
select.select_by_value('2008')

# find "search" button and click it
button = browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphMain_btnSearch')
button.click()

# display results 
table = browser.find_element_by_id('search_results')
for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:-1]:
    print [cell.text for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')]

# close the browser
browser.close()
```

Prints:

```
[u'ABERCROMBIE, HON.NEIL', u'HI01', u'2008', u'FD Amendment']
[u'ABERCROMBIE, HON.NEIL', u'HI01', u'2008', u'FD Original']
[u'ACKERMAN, HON.GARY L.', u'NY05', u'2008', u'FD Amendment']
[u'ACKERMAN, HON.GARY L.', u'NY05', u'2008', u'FD Amendment']
...
```